# sql selection to arraylist android

Tags: sql, android, listview, arraylist, request

How can we take data from sql with a sql request like "SELECT * FROM ..." to an arraylist (more precise in a listview or a autocompletetext or a spinner).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i suggest you take a look at the NotepadDemo [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html)

there they use a SimpleCursorAdapter to build a ListView

cheers